# Firebase dynamic links (smartlink) is not redirecting to the custom url if app is not installed

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Currently I have a requirement in which I want to create a firebase smartlink where browser should redirect to a custom url instead of app or appstore when app is not installed in the device.

I believe it is isolated from the framework which we are using for frontend mobile app, in my case I am using flutter.

I am trying to add custom url as per below screenshot, there is field for it under "deeplink behaviour for apple". let me know if I am missing anything. I have also tried to create that link manually with the help of query parameters (ifl, ofl, afl) but that doesn't work too. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually it was easy to identify the root cause, we just need to check Debug console in the Firebase dynamic link. Whitelisting of the custom url was missing. This is how I fixed the issue.

Comment: Where do we need to define regex for whitelisting of url. I couldn't find the page ?

Comment: @SurjeetSingh On Dynamic Links page, click the More button (three dots) -> Allowlist URL pattern. You can find more here:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429

Comment: Thank you @Suresh Sharma. This is super useful information.